# WooCommerce Webhooks Auth (secret & signature) - how to use

Tags: node.js, wordpress, api, hash, woocommerce

I'm trying to create an integration between [**WooCommerce Webhook API**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/) and my Node.js backend. However, I can't really figure out how I'm suppose to use the secret to authenticate the request.

`secret:` an optional secret key that is used to generate a `HMAC-SHA256` hash of the request body so the receiver can verify authenticity of the webhook.

`X-WC-Webhook-Signature:` a Base64 encoded HMAC-SHA256 hash of the payload.

**WooCommerce backend:**
(Hemmelighed = "Secret")
[image]

**Nodejs backend:**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var secret = 'ciPV6gjCbu&efdgbhfgj&¤"#&¤GDA';
    var signature = req.header("x-wc-webhook-signature");
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(req.body, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    if(hash === signature){
        res.send('match');
    } else {
        res.send("no match");
    }

});
```

Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/5941

[WooCommerce REST API source](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#webhooks)

The hash and the signature doesn't match. What is wrong?

**Update:**
`console.log` returns these values:

`hash`: pU9kXddJPY9MG9i2ZFLNTu3TXZA++85pnwfPqMr0dg0=

`signature`: PjKImjr9Hk9MmIdUMc+pEmCqBoRXA5f3Ac6tnji7exU=

`hash (without .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64))`: a54f645dd7493d8f4c1bd8b66452cd4eedd35d903efbce699f07cfa8caf4760d

Comment: Are you maybe using `bodyParser`? `req.body` is not necessarily a string.

Comment: @fingeron Yes, I'm using bodyParser. I've updated the codesnippet. I've tried var body = req.body.toString('utf8'); aswell, but doesn't help.

Comment: @Unicco Would you add console.log() for both hash and signature. (hash without toString() add with toString() )

Comment: @gokcand I've updated the question.

Comment: @gokcand Sorry for the delay. I havn't really had the time to check it out yet. I implemented your solution yesterday, but were getting some errors. I didn't have the time to fix these. I'll look more deeply into your answer today. Have you tested it yourself?

Comment: Yeah, no problem @Unicco. I'm just joking. :) Unfortunately, I don't have a WooCommerce account but I'm %99 sure that second way will work in your case. Ping me when you are implementing it so we can continue our discussion in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @gokcand I've a working sample now. Thanks for the help. Could you please edit your answer to something like this (these two gist works): https://gist.github.com/Excelautomation/230de62989f26e9fa54a1cc2240148f8 and I've reward you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The signature needs to be checked against the body and not the JSON it contains. i.e. **the raw bytes of the req.body**.

### Modify the `bodyParser` first:

```
const rawBodySaver = (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
  if (buf && buf.length) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
  }
};

app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: rawBodySaver }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ verify: rawBodySaver, extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ verify: rawBodySaver, type: '*/*' }));
```

### and then, using [**crypto**](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) (it is distributed with node you don't need to `npm install` anything.)

```
import crypto from 'crypto'; //Let's try with built-in crypto lib instead of cryptoJS

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const secret = 'ciPV6gjCbu&efdgbhfgj&¤"#&¤GDA';
  const signature = req.header("X-WC-Webhook-Signature");

  const hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', secret).update(req.rawBody).digest('base64');

  if(hash === signature){
    res.send('match');
  } else {
    res.send("no match");
  }
});
```

---

Comment: Thank you. You need to change req.header[""] to req.header(""). I'm sorry, but the signature and hash don't match. These are the outputs after implementing the buffer: hash: pU9kXddJPY9MG9i2ZFLNTu3TXZA++85pnwfPqMr0dg0= signature: 2Od/YW7laO4EtqdsO3CvOcXPTIeFCY5qVZdKdWSJcKU=

Comment: If I remove bodyparser, the req.body is just empty. I've tried changing the private secret key to something more simple - nor does this help. I believe bodyparser is required in order to access the body; nevertheless I'm not sure how I can access it differently.

Comment: @Unicco Yeah, true we need bodyParser to access req.body. I have updated the answer, can you please check it again? Especially, try the second way.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these approaches out as soon as possible, and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below will save someone some time.

```
// Make sure to add a WISTIA_SECRET_KEY in your Environment Variables
// See https://docs.pipedream.com/environment-variables/
const secret = process.env.SELF_AUTOMATE_KEY;
const signature = event.headers["x-wc-webhook-signature"];
const body = steps.trigger.raw_event["body_b64"];
const clean_Body = body.replace("body_b64: ", "");
//const body = steps.trigger.raw_event;
console.log(event.headers["x-wc-webhook-signature"]);

console.log("Print Body", clean_Body);

if (process.env.SELF_AUTOMATE_KEY === undefined) {
  $end("No WISTIA_SECRET_KEY environment variable defined. Exiting.")
}

if (!("x-wc-webhook-signature" in event.headers)) {
  $end("No x-wc-webhook-signature header present in the request. Exiting.")
}

// Once we've confirmed we have a signature, we want to 
// validate it by generating an HMAC SHA-256 hexdigest
const crypto = require('crypto');

const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256',
  secret).update(JSON.stringify(clean_Body), 'base64').digest('base64');



console.log(hash);
// $end() ends the execution of a pipeline, presenting a nice message in the "Messages"
// column in the inspector above. See https://docs.pipedream.com/notebook/code/#end
if (hash !== signature) {
  $end("The correct secret key was not passed in the event. Exiting!")
}
```